# convert SDP constraint to nonlinear (nonconvex) one

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have an optimization problem with the following SDP constraint:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}\gamma I-\Gamma & \gamma\Sigma\\ \gamma\Sigma & Z\end{bmatrix}\geq 0
\end{equation*}
where $\Gamma\in\mathbb{S}^{n}, Z\in\mathbb{S}_+, \gamma\in\mathbb{R}_+$ are optimization variables, while $\Sigma\in\mathbb{S}^n$ is a constant vector.

How can I reformulate this constraint into a nonlinear (nonconvex) one? I have tried using Schur complement, but because of $Z$ I still get a positive semidefinite constraint.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to formulate this without a semidefiniteness constraint?  The $Z$ matrix must be PSD in order for the whole block matrix to be PSD and there's no connection between $Z$ and the other parts of the matrix.

Comment: I have multiple constraints of a similar form. But besides the semidefiniteness constraints, I have a few nonconvex equality constraints. So I would like to make the problem into a general nonconvex form.

Comment: One (not very successful in most cases and I can't recommend it) approach to such problems is to parameterize the PSD matrix $Z$ as $Z=X^{T}X$ where $X$ is an unrestricted matrix variable of the same size (or you can limit the rank of $Z$ by limiting the number of rows of $X$.)

Comment: Then how will it help? I will still have the matrix inequality in the Schur complement, no?

Comment: You could apply the matrix factorization to the entire block matrix.

Comment: What if I apply Sylvester's criterion and replace the semidefinite constraint with a list of determinant constraints?

Comment: You could try that, but an $n$ by $n$ matrix has $2^{n}-1$ principal minors and as $n$ grows the formula for each determinant becomes much more complicated.  It isn't practical.